# Combining FOR and IF in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there anyway to make this into a single statement in python ?

```
name = 'Customer_Identify'
useless_list = ['id']
# I Want to make the 3 following lines into a single line. It should return True.
for i in useless_list:
    if (i in name.lower()):
        print(True)
```

I tried with lambda functions but I maybe doing some mistake somewhere. :(

Comment: you might want a list comprehension like `filtered = [i for i in useless_list if i in name.lower()]`

Comment: Why? It's perfectly readable as it is

Comment: I suggest that you learn about list comprehensions and generator expressions

Comment: If you are only going to print, no need to change anything IMO...

Comment: Your question is very unclear and hence different types of answers here. Do you want to return a single value, or print multiple times??? this changes the answers!

Comment: If any one values in useless_list exists in the "name" the code must return True. else False.

Comment: Well, that makes all but 1 answer here irrelevant... Try to be more clear in the question which by the way it is still not clear are you trying to print or return... everytime you say something else

Comment: @Tomerikoo okay :) Thanks for your kind comments :) I will be clear from next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question asked that it should return true.
how about this ?

`return any(i in name.lower() for i in useless_list)`

Comment: Not sure that's the same functionality... Here you return/print one boolean value if any of the values are in name. In the OP, only `True` is printed **for each** value that is in name...

Comment: @Tomerikoo The comment in the OP's code states it wants to return the value, i just assume the print was used unintentionally perhaps ?

Comment: Oh didn't notice that comment and in that case I guess that satisfies the problem. It is indeed a little unclear... Actually, if that is really the intention I guess this is the best answer

Answer (score 3):

How about using generator expressions?

```
print('\n'.join(str(True) for i in useless_list if i in name.lower()))
```

Comment: That's not a list anymore :)

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Spot on, sir!

Comment: Another similar way without the use of `join` is unpacking with `print`'s extra arguments. Something like: `print(*(True for i in useless_list if i in name.lower()), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'Customer_Identify'
useless_list = ['id', 'AA']

[print (item in name.lower()) for item in useless_list]
```

output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty awful, but you can use a list comprehension to actually invoke `print`:

```
[print(True) for i in useless_list if i in name.lower()]
```

Of course, that builds a totally useless list of `None`s...